# numeric to minutes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

I need to convert the numeric value into minute value in SQL Server.

For example, let us consider the input variable `@ScheduleTime` of type `numeric(38,2)` and the output variable `@NumberOfMinutes` of type `int`.

Given `@ScheduleTime = 2.35` (which means 2 hours 35 minutes), I need the output to be `@NumberOfMinutes = 155`

Comment: Sounds like you just need to multiply by 60...

Comment: Note that .35 means 35 minutes

Comment: i need to multiply the value before decimal point by 60 and need to add the value after decimal point. I would like to know how to separate the values before and after decimal points

Comment: Sure, well you can see either answer for an example. Take a look at the Modulo operator... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @ScheduleTime numeric(38,2)
set @ScheduleTime = 2.35

declare @NumberOfMinutes int
set @NumberOfMinutes = FLOOR(@ScheduleTime) * 60 + (@ScheduleTime % 1) * 100

print @NumberOfMinutes
```